# CSS RGBA color background behaving strange

Tags: html, css

Ive tried to use the `rgba()` to define a div's background color, but instead of changing the opacity, the fourth value changes brightness (apparently), and rendering the rounded borders black. Here is my CSS, really simple stuff:

```
#content {
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(169, 245, 208, 0.4);
}
```

And here is a picture of this issue in both Firefox and Chrome:
[image: Ultra weird bug]
Finally, the URL of the site: http://lksonorizacao.com.br/newsite/

Comment: I don't see any element with `id="content"`. And the page doesn't look like your images...

Comment: @oriol the link was wrong, should be correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#container` parent has a `background:#000` set on it. `#content`’s rounded corners are just revealing that black. `rgba()` does work the way you think it should.